# Bamboo: Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher

Tags: linux, ant, centos, bamboo

I'm having a heck of a time getting Ant to run from Bamboo.

My install directory for Ant is `/usr/bin/ant` - I've tried the `ls -al /usr/bin/ant` to see if it was just a symlink but it doesn't return a different path.

In Bamboo I've set the Path to `/usr` as setting it to `/usr/bin/ant` gives me an error that `/usr/bin/ant/bin/ant` cannot be found. Hitting the "Detect server capabilities" button changes it to `/usr` anyway. So that should be right.

Then I read that my ANT_HOME variable is probably incorrect so I set it with:

`export ANT_HOME=/usr/bin/ant`

I still seem to be getting the same error in the title. Not sure if there's anything else I have to do.

I'm running on CentOS 7.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure `/usr/bin/ant` is a directory? On Unix systems, files under `/usr/bin` are usually executable files, not subdirectories. `ANT_HOME` must point to a directory, not an executable. See [CentOS how to update Ant Version to 1.8.x and higher?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115586/centos-how-to-update-ant-version-to-1-8-x-and-higher) for a possible solution.

Comment: It's not a directory. `/usr/bin/ant` was the path to the executable. I went ahead and changed `ANT_HOME` to `/usr/bin` but I still get the same error.

Comment: So I decided to try running `ant -version` in the command line and it gave me an error that `JAVA_HOME` wasn't set up correct. So I set that variable and ran `ant -version` again and once again get the error in the title.

Comment: Ant distributive contains of ./bin/ant script and ./lib/*.jar libraries. When Bamboo starts Ant then ant script can't find that lib folder. It's better to point Ant capability to folder with bin and lib directories

Answer (score 1):

I came to this because I was having the same problem with the same paths that you were.  I had forgotten about the *Detect Server Capabilities* button and when I hit that it showed the correct path being: **/usr/share/ant** which works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade your jdk to 1.8 ?
I think it is the bug of jdk-1.8 .

The error occured after my jdk be upgraded to 1.8 and I resolved it by the steps:

1. Create the dir for jdk-1.8

   mkdir /usr/share/java-1.8.0

   mkdir /usr/lib/java-1.8.0
2. Modify the file "/usr/share/java-utils/java-functions":

   diff ./java-functions_old /usr/share/java-utils/java-functions

   149,150c149,150

   --             -e '/java (full )*version "/s/'$re'/<<<\1>>>/' \

   --             -e '/java (full )*version "/s/.*<<<([^>]{1,})>>>.*/\1/p')

   ---

   ++             -e '/[java|openjdk] (full )*version "/s/'$re'/<<<\1>>>/' \

   ++             -e '/[java|openjdk] (full )*version "/s/.*<<<([^>]\ {1,})>>>.*/\1/p')